# Interaction between variables in regression analysis and its effect

Tags: regression, correlation, data-visualization, interaction

I regularly have to work in regression framework (not always linear regression), and have to deal with multiple variables at a time. One main issue that I found is inclusion of some variables make either change the sign of some other variable or make them insignificant.

I read many tread here as well as other literature where it explained the reason behind it.

My question is, is there a visual way to keep track of how variables are affecting other variables when we are including them in regression analysis. I came across this [blog](http://andrewgelman.com/2013/05/26/how-to-understand-coefficients-that-reverse-sign-when-you-start-controlling-for-things/) and articles referenced there. Since it's a published article, no code is given. I'm looking for something like this but with example codes.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: An excellent book I'd recommend is Michael Mitchell's [Interpreting and Visualizing Regression Models Using Stata](http://www.amazon.com/Interpreting-Visualizing-Regression-Models-Using/dp/1597181072). It dedicated four chapters, more than 120 pages, to discuss and demonstrate how to visualize interactions between different types of variables (categorical and continuous.) Even if you do not use Stata, the syntax is plain enough for readers to apply onto other software packages.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I had a look at this book and it seems it has what I'm looking for. I also found a package in R called "visreg". Exploring that as well.